# MongoDB: $and operator not working in Bulk updates using the Node.JS driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

I'm trying to use the [Bulk update API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/) in MongoDB 3.0.4 from Node.js. It's strange that I got the error below if operators such as `$and` or `$ne` are used. Simple queries work though.

```
WriteError({"code":9,"index":0,"errmsg":"Unknown modifier: $and","op":{"q":{"$and":[{"id":49689},{"status":{"$ne":4}}]},"u":{"$and":[{"id":49689},{"status":{"$ne":4}}]},"multi":true,"upsert":false}})
```

Below is some test code in CoffeeScript:

```
  bulk = db.mongo.collection('route-segments').initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
  filter = $and: [
      { id: 49689 }
      { status: $ne: 4 }
  ]
  # filter = id: segStatus.id # <-- this works
  bulk.find(filter).updateOne(filter, $set: status: 4)
  bulk.execute (err, result) ->
    console.log "err = #{err}"
```

I tried the same command in Mongo shell and it worked:

```
> bulk=c.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
{ "nInsertOps" : 0, "nUpdateOps" : 0, "nRemoveOps" : 0, "nBatches" : 0 }
> bulk.find({ $and: [{id: 49689}, {status: {$ne: 4}}]}).updateOne( {$set: {status: 4}})
> bulk.execute()
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 1,
    "nModified" : 1,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

MongoDB version: 3.0.4
MongoDB Node.js driver: 2.0.35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `filter` in the updateOne method.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1

Comment: Oops, thanks! That's really a silly (and expensive) typo that puzzled me for quite a while.

Comment: You're welcome, I know that story! Often, the best solution is to rewrite the part which is a problem from scratch!